# Pueden muchos Tablespaces compartir entre ellos un solo datafile?

Tags: sql, oracle

Entiendo que un Tablespace puede tener muchos datafiles pero mi duda es si entre los Tablespace pueden compartir solo un datafile. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Un datafile, solo puede pertenecer a un tablespace exclusivamente. Y un tablespace puede tener uno o varios datafiles, pero no compartirlos entre tablespaces.

Aqui puedes leer un poco acerca de la estructura de oracle. 
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/physical.htm#CNCPT1112

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!